# What is the general procedure to install development libraries in Ubuntu?

Tags: libraries, sdl

I am having a pretty tough time installing the latest development libraries of SDL in my Ubuntu 12.04. Last year, I somehow managed to install **libsdl 1.2-dev** for Ubuntu. As far as I remember, I did it using *Synaptic Package Manager*. Now, I want to work with the latest SDL libraries. 
In the page containing downloads for SDL version 2.0.0 (which is the latest stable version), under **Linux** section for **Development Libraries**, it is given

> Please contact your distribution maintainer for updates.

It would help me a lot if someone answered these questions:

1. Why is it so *not simple* to install dev libraries in Ubuntu?
2. Can anyone give an exhaustive list of the ways to install these libraries on the system so that one can use them for programming?
3. It would be helpful if you can give the above answer taking the latest SDL dev libraries as an example. Also what is the procedure to clean all the previous versions from the system while installing the latest versions?

PS: I searched for the libsdl-dev package on Synaptic Package Manager, but it is not showing up the latest version.

Comment: Debian-based systems (including Ubuntu) can simply do "sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0" to get the library installed system-wide, and all sorts of other useful dependencies, too. "sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev" will install everything necessary to build programs that use SDL (https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to download the source and compile the libs.

You also need some dependencies before compile SDL2. So **install these packages first**:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential xorg-dev libudev-dev libts-dev libgl1-mesa-dev \
libglu1-mesa-dev libasound2-dev libpulse-dev libopenal-dev libogg-dev \
libvorbis-dev libaudiofile-dev libpng12-dev libfreetype6-dev libusb-dev \
libdbus-1-dev zlib1g-dev libdirectfb-dev
```

- *Method 1: Source code archive*
  Now you can go to [the libsdl download page](http://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) and download `SDL2-2.0.0.tar.gz`, extract the archive (you can extract the archive using tar: `tar -xvzf SDL2-2.0.0.tar.gz`), `cd` into the directory created, and run the following commands (**don't forget to install the dependencies mentioned above, before starting to compile**):

  ```
  ./configure
  make
  sudo make install
  ```
- *Method 2: Mercurial repository*
  Another way to install SDL2 is to download SDL from the mercurial repository online. In order to do this you have to install mercurial first:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install mercurial
  ```

  then download SDL (SDL will be downloaded into the directory you're using the terminal)

  ```
  hg clone http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL
  ```

  now go into the downloaded SDL directory and build & install (**don't forget to install the dependencies mentioned above, before starting to compile**) the libs by running:

  ```
  cd SDL
  ./configure
  make
  sudo make install
  ```

Don't forget to run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

to update the necessary links and cache to the libraries.

**Code::Blocks**
Add to
**Project > Build options > Compiler settings > Other options > -lSDL2**

and to
**Project > Build options > Linker settings > Other linker options -lSDL2**

Remember to add these to the Project options and not only to **Debug** or **Release** settings. Also, if you've already wrongly compiled the sources, remember to Rebuild it (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the great answer! All the commands work so well together. I use codeblocks, and it is not detecting the libraries. What are the changes that I need to make in my Codeblocks environment so that I can use these libraries?

Comment: New project-> SDL Project

Comment: It still shows the error, "fatal error: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory", when compiled. For the previous SDL version (I installed it using Synaptic Package manager), I had to add these in the Linker options: `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL_image, for the above error to be gone. What is to be done in this scenario?

Comment: You can compile it using gcc by adding -lSDL2 to gcc. For example: `gcc source.c -lSDL2`. I don't know how to do this with codeblocks, but I'm downloading codeblocks and I'll try and let you know.

Comment: I found out how to compile add these flags from codeblocks. I'm gonna edit my answer on how to do this.

Comment: Btw, it's ***SDL2/SDL.h***   NOT SDL/SDL.h

Comment: The answer is just PERFECT with respect to SDL dev libraries, which infact was my actual need at this time. But, how did you know what are all the dependencies that were to be installed and other details(dev library specific or otherwise also). Because expecting a reply to all the minute details is not fair on my part and also it would make the answer insanely large, can you suggest me some link which contains material to read over, which can help beginners understand this topic from basics.

Comment: The 'build-essential' it's a meta-package, as you can read here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages too, meta-packages packages do not contain actual software, they simply depend on other packages to be installed. In this case packages needed to compile C/C++ sources. The other SDL2 dependencies, I took them from the internet. The "installation procedure" it's always the same in Linux. There is the configure script which makes the Makefile that you will use to make (compile) and make install (install) the program (there's always a README file included which tells how to use this)

Comment: Anyway you can check the Ubuntu Wiki for tons of useful guides: https://help.ubuntu.com/community and also this lin for general linux guides: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ExternalGuides

Comment: `gcc -Wall -o module.out module.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2)` also works the same way as with `-lSDL2`

Comment: Debian-based systems (including Ubuntu) can simply do "sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0" to get the library installed system-wide, and all sorts of other useful dependencies, too. "sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev" will install everything necessary to build programs that use SDL (https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation)

Comment: @PeppeDAlterio Where did it installed? "dpkg -L sdl2" says "package 'sdl2' is not installed".

Answer (score 11):

You can also do:

If you just want the libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0
```

If you want to do development:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```