# Where are the compiled SDL libraries?

Tags: c++, libraries, sdl

I compiled the SDL 2 libraries as described here [What is the general procedure to install development libraries in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344512/what-is-the-general-procedure-to-install-development-libraries-in-ubuntu)

What I would like to know, is where are these libraries actually located after compiling/installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of this question answered their own question [in an edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/404536/2):

> SDL can be found in `/usr/local/lib` instead of `/usr/lib`, which is where I was pointed to after online research.

Comment: No they are not there, at least not on my system (Ubuntu) ... I can compile with g++ and -lSDL2 but cannot find the SDL library files (not the headers which are in /usr/include) , any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've installed libsdl2-dev on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

run this command to search for SDL2 libraries:

```
find /usr/lib -name SDL2
```

reveals:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SDL2
```