# Ubuntu 15.10 Installing SDL2

Tags: software-installation, perl, sdl

I have ubuntu 15.10 running as a virtual machine I would like to install and use SDL2, I followed this process [What is the general procedure to install development libraries in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344512/what-is-the-general-procedure-to-install-development-libraries-in-ubuntu)
as well as the instruction for Ubuntu [from here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation):

I got no errors or anything when installing SDL2 but somehow it just won't compile with the following error:

```
Can't locate SDL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the SDL module)...
```

which means I didn't install SDL2 correctly somehow :/

Has anyone got an idea how I can check if it is installed properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easiest way is to just install by apt-get...

If you just want the libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0
```

On Bionic or newer:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0
```

If you want to do development:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

Comment: `libsdl2-2.0` --> `libsdl2-2.0-0 `